# What does "variété à coins" translate to in English?

Tags: translation

I am attempting to translate Borel's "Cohomologie de $\text{SL}_{n}$ et valeurs de fonctions zeta aux points entiers" paper into English. Since I know no French, this is a rather crude process heavily involving Google Translate (and also a little common sense). However, I am unable to interpret the phrase "variété à coins". I am led to believe that this translates to something like "wedge variety" or "corner variety". Neither of these terms are familiar to me and a quick Google search turned up nothing, which leads me to my question...

Would someone be kind enough to provide me with an English translation of the phrase "variété à coins"?

For completeness, I include the sentence where the phrase is to be found:-

"Mais en fait la construction précédente fournit une autre démonstration de l’injectivité de $j^{*}_{\Gamma}$; qui, à l’encontre de celle de [4], ne fait pas intervenir la compactification de $X/\Gamma$ en une variété à coins (cf. 5.6)."

The reference for the paper is:-

Borel, Armand. Cohomologie de $\text{SL}_{n}$ et valeurs de fonctions zeta aux points entiers. Ann. Sc. Norm. Super. Pisa 4 (1977) 613-636.

Comment: I think the common english name is "manifold with corner". I'm not sure this question is appropriate for MO, thought...

Comment: @Adrien Aha, thank you very much. I apologise if this question is not appropriate, and am willing to delete it if that is the done thing? I am curious though; why is this question not suitable for MO? I often see similar translation requests on here.

Comment: Yes. It translates to "manifold with corners".

Comment: Adrien, I things this questions is perfectly appropriate. It arises in translating a research-level book, and it's a question that only practitioners of the field can answer, so where else?

Comment: I also think this is a fine question.

Comment: I just said I wasn't sure :) Without any precise reasons, I must say, apologies.

Comment: @Adrien That's cool. Perhaps you might like to make your comment an answer so that I may accept it? It certainly seems to answer the question.

Comment: Ok, that'll be my shortest answer so far !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The translation is "manifold with corners".